# More efficient way to handle big lists in python?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance

I'm writing a python script to solve this exercise:

> Given in input a vector V of N integers we want to find, for each size between 1 and N, the maximum
> of the minimum’s of every contiguous subsequence in the vector.

The script I wrote works fine with N<1000 but when I try it with greater values, it just keeps running without ending. I guessed it's too slow because of the 3 for-loops and the many .append() to big lists, but how can I solve that? Or am I wrong and there is another problem I don't see?

```
f_name = input("Inserire nome del file: ")
 
f_in = open("inputs/"+f_name, "r")
f_out = open("outputs/"+f_name, "w")
 
# n = int(input())
n = int(f_in.readline())
 
v_s = f_in.readline().rstrip('\n').split()
v = [int(i) for i in v_s]
 
maxs = []
 
for size in range(1, n+1):
    mins = []
    for i in range(n):
        subseq = []
        if (i+size <= n):
            for j in range(size):
                subseq.append(v[i+j])
        if (len(subseq) > 0):
            mins.append(min(subseq))
    maxs.append(max(mins))
 
for max in maxs:
    f_out.write(str(max) + " ")
 
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

[Here are some examples of input and output.](https://cyberchallenge.it/assets/programming-test/2020-maxofmin-dataset.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-of-minimums-for-every-window-size-in-a-given-array/) (with some readability improvements):

```
def fill(array, auxiliary, my_range):
    s = []
    for i in my_range:
        while s and array[s[-1]] >= array[i]:
            s.pop()

        if s:
            auxiliary[i] = s[-1]
        s.append(i)


def solution(array, n, left, right):
    ans = [0] * (n + 1)
    for i in range(n):
        my_len = right[i] - left[i] - 1
        ans[my_len] = max(ans[my_len], array[i])

    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        ans[i] = max(ans[i], ans[i + 1])
    return ans[1:]


def main(filename):

    with open("{}/{}".format("input", filename), "r") as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()

    n = int(lines[0])
    v = [int(s.strip()) for s in lines[-1].split()]

    left = [-1] * (n + 1)
    right = [n] * (n + 1)

    fill(v, left, range(n))
    fill(v, right, range(n-1, -1, -1))
    result = solution(v, n, left, right)
    result = [str(res) for res in result]

    output = " ".join(result)
    with open("{}/{}".format("output", filename), "w") as fp:
        fp.write(output)
    print(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_name = input("Inserire nome del file: ")
    main(f_name)
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I'll need all the contiguous subsequences of v, so `array_split(v, i)` won't give me all the combinations I think...
Is there a way I can get all the subsequences of v from size 1 to size n without using 3 nested for-loops (one for scrolling size, one for scrolling v and one for getting `size` elements starting from the current one)?

Comment: I had misunderstood the assignment, now it should be fine. I suggest you to look the resource of the link, in order to have a better understanding about how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The appends in python are pretty fast, but your algorithm is too slow -- you have three nested loops which have on the order of N elements each, with total complexity of O(n^3).

This means that with careful optimization, maybe you can handle 2000 values or 3000 values... but your biggest example is 500000 values, so this is not going to help.

If you want to solve this, you need to rewrite the program so it does not have three nested loops. This problem is well-known, and you can find solutions on the internet with no nested loops, O(n) complexity.

Comment: Thank you! So using arrays instead of lists wouldn't fix my efficiency issue, would it?
However, if the problem is with the 3 nested loops I really have no idea on how to avoid them, since I need to get all contiguous subsequences of V... Do you have any suggestion/useful link?